# PHP Encryption and Decryption - High Level

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I need to create a good strong encryption system for a client. It would be used for storing sensitive user information. I just wanted to get some advice off someone who has more experience in this area. It sounds like 256 bit AES would be my best option.

What I was thinking was http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes-php.html

And for the key, perhaps using a hash of something unique to each user?

Does this sound like a sufficient idea?

Comment: Why ask if you answer your own question?

Comment: I just need to check to make sure I'm doing the right thing and get some advice on the encryption key. Cheers.

Comment: What are the threats you're trying to protect yourself from? It's hard to make an assessment without more specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHA only works one-way (same as for examples MD5 before anyone suggests this). I think he also want a way to easily decrypt and read the stored data when he needs to.

AES is indeed a very good option. I would use the same.

Will you deploy your solution on a shared hosting environment? Be sure to chmod the file with your encryption/decryption key so no other user can access it. There's no point in locking a house and leaving the key right in front of the door.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. It's a 2 dedicated web servers, 1 dedicated DB server and a loadbalancer all behind a dedicated firewall. With regards to the key, would it be better to have a single key in a file outside the web root, or maybe use a SHA256 hash of a salt for each user, stored in the DB?

Comment: I would use a single key outside the document root. Storing a hash in the DB for each user won't do it as you would also need to encrypt that hash/key somehow. If somebody gets access to your DB, they will have both the key and the encrypted data instead of just the encrypted data.

Comment: Using a single key means you get nearly no protection from encrypting the data. PHP will have access to the key file. If the web server is compromised, all your data is exposed. You're basically just encrypting the communication between the web server and the database server. The likelihood of an intruder getting through the firewall while unable to get into the web server is rather low.

Comment: If you encrypt data using a unique key per user and encrypt the key itself using the SHA of the user's password, then the keys are not stored in the plain on the web server. If a hacker gains control of it, he can only get the data of the users who are currently logged in. The problem with this scheme, of course, is that there's no easy way to reset a user's password.

Comment: If a hacker can get past the firewall, he could also simply add some keylogger code to parts of the target website and sit back and relax. At some point you need to consider part of your infrastructure as reliable. Else you can keep securing and adding extra safeguards till infinity. A firewall should be such a part imho.

Comment: Thanks. Both good comments. I think a combination of the 2 might be best. Ref: [link](http://www.net-security.org/dl/articles/Key_Management_Procedures.pdf) So a key offline used to decrypt a key in the database unique to each user. The user passwords are SHA256 with a salt so hopefully a keylogger shouldn't be a problem. As far as my plans I think that's the most detail I should go into in a public forum. Any more thoughts are welcomed. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

AES is best encryption to Use. :)

I’ve been using an AES encryption class for a little over a year now, and it is an excellent way to use FIPS Compliant AES encryption in php. The script comes in a free version (ECB mode only) and a paid version for only $10.

This is a completely standalone class that does not require the mcrypt library, and has php4 and php5 support. Encryption is available in 128, 192, and 256 bit, depending on the cipher length.

Using it is easy as this:

```
include("AES.class.php");

$my_256_key = 'MpDsw*8cQM&fez*7eBoZB^W*kP652NoW';
$initialization_vector = 'WmR&z28zWn8r*9$R';

$aes = new AES($my_256_key, "CBC", $initialization_vector);

$string_to_encrypt = 'SOME STRING OF TEXT, OR EVEN AN ENTIRE FILE';

$encrypted_string = $aes->encrypt($string_to_encrypt);

$original_string = $aes->decrypt($encrypted_string);
```

The cipher modes that are supported are: Electronic Codebook (ECB), Cipher Block Chaining (CBC), Cipher Feedback (CFB), and Output Feedback (OFB). –Block Cipher Modes »

If you are needing to integrate real encryption into a script, I highly recommend this class. It’s strong enough for storing sensitive data like credit cards (key management is another topic), and has an extremely easy interface.

Keep in mind that encryption is only as secure as the key and the key management that is used. Unlike using hash functions (Md5, SHA1), encryption can be reversed, and will considerably slow down a PHP script, especially so for encrypting large amounts of data.